# Mouseless Drag and Drop - change how the event are raised (raise drop/drag event programatically)

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect

(first the question then I'll explain)

**How to tell the application to drop an object/raise the drop event programatically (I'm not using the mouse)?**

I'm currently developing for the MSKinect, and I want to implement a Drag and Drop really close to the native drag and drop (see [msdn doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859.aspx)).

I've already implemented a drag and drop using a canvas and using the event raised by the Kinect cursors to "drag" things around. but I'm more interested in transferring data using the drag and drop.

I know that usually the drop event is launched when the mouse button is released, I want to make the draggableElement release when a given gesture occurs.

Additional information: I'm implementing a Manager based on the [LesterLobo's work](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2008/02/26/drag-drop-library-updated.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can globally simulate mouse movements and clicks using the [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function of the Win32 API. You can find instructions on how to call the function using C# [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.sendinput).

The `SendInput` function is as close as it gets to actually using the mouse. Unfortunately, it's not very convenient to work with. You will have to simulate pressing the left mouse button, moving the mouse, and releasing the left mouse button.

Please note that this approach is intended for dragging stuff across applications, as well as within the application. If you would just like to drag stuff around within the application, there is most likely a simpler solution.

Comment: I think that bypassing the mouse using SendInput could work however I'd rather only raise an event in the code behind (the same way we could raise a Click event). I don't want to use the mouse (or its input) at all because I've got two cursors with the Kinect for two different users (ie 4 cursors). I don't want any concurrency over this function: there is possibly 4 drag and drop at the same time.